# How to pass additional parameter when requesting for token

Tags: .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I am trying to get access token from azure AD, however one additional parameter
`resource` is not present when request is send to `/oauth2/token` endpoint

Is it possible somehow to add additional parameter? I cannot find any class to override

```
AADSTS50001: Resource identifier is not provided

c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme
                {
                    Type = "oauth2",
                    Flow = "accessCode",
                    AuthorizationUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{_configuration["Auth:Tanent:TanentId"]}/oauth2/authorize",
                    TokenUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{_configuration["Auth:Tanent:TanentId"]}/oauth2/token",
                });
```

Example request

```
// Line breaks for legibility only

POST /{tenant}/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
grant_type=authorization_code
&client_id=2d4d11a2-f814-46a7-890a-274a72a7309e
&code=AwABAAAAvPM1KaPlrEqdFSBzjqfTGBCmLdgfSTLEMPGYuNHSUYBrqqf_ZT_p5uEAEJJ_nZ3UmphWygRNy2C3jJ239gV_DBnZ2syeg95Ki-374WHUP-i3yIhv5i-7KU2CEoPXwURQp6IVYMw-DjAOzn7C3JCu5wpngXmbZKtJdWmiBzHpcO2aICJPu1KvJrDLDP20chJBXzVYJtkfjviLNNW7l7Y3ydcHDsBRKZc3GuMQanmcghXPyoDg41g8XbwPudVh7uCmUponBQpIhbuffFP_tbV8SNzsPoFz9CLpBCZagJVXeqWoYMPe2dSsPiLO9Alf_YIe5zpi-zY4C3aLw5g9at35eZTfNd0gBRpR5ojkMIcZZ6IgAA
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12345
&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F
&client_secret=p@ssw0rd

//NOTE: client_secret only required for web apps
```

`&resource` is not being send by default, and i want to add it somehow.

Comment: Add additional parameter to what? - which resource are you missing?

Comment: I edited my question, check Example request section